# Convert JsonObject into String using Java

Tags: java, json, mongodb, gson

I am getting some values from mongodb via Java Spring API.  For `sofTagList`  as in image below, I am getting `List<JsonObject>` for that.  I am trying to access the `value` field inside `tagName`.  When I itereate the list, I am getting null values each and every time. I tried googling and convert that JsonObject to String.  But that doesn't help me to solve my issue.  I am using `com.google.gson.JsonObject` package.  Here is the screen shot of my mongodb which I am trying to access.

[image: Screen Shot of mongodb, JsonObject]

Edit 1:  Added code Snippet.

```
if(null!=person.getSofTagList()){
                    List<JsonObject> jsonObj = person.getSofTagList();
                    System.out.println("Size is   ========>>  "+ jsonObj.size());
                    for (JsonObject jsonObject : jsonObj) {
                        System.out.println("GetTag Name         "+jsonObject.getAsJsonObject("tagName"));                       
                    }
                }
```

When printing size I am getting 30 as shown in image.  It loops for 30 times in for loop but all time null is the output.
Hope my question is clear.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: @NiksTyagi: Just check.  I added some code.

Comment: @Java Beginer You can attach a debug breakpoint in Eclipse inside the loop and check the content of `jsonObject`, if any.

Comment: Okay. Let me try and know the result @Rakesh.

Answer (score 0):

Update the code inside the for loop as below :

```
 JSONArray msg = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("tagName");
            Iterator<String> iterator = msg.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(iterator.next());
            }
```

Comment: @Java Beginer can you update the code and let me knw the result

Comment: Sure.  I'll let you know.  BTW - This JSONArray belongs to which package??

Comment: org.json.simple.JSONArray;

Comment: ohh my mistake i talk JSONObject instead of JsonObject.wait me check other solution

Comment: Sorry sorry.  I mistakenly put the given snippet outside for loop.  Now I changed.  But getting some other weird error from eclipse. "Cannot cast from JsonElement to JSONArray"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46817/discussion-between-niks-tyagi-and-java-beginer)